# Calling cv::cuda::HOG from python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, boost-python

I need to access the cuda modules of opencv in C++ from python. I tried wrapping the c++ functions using Boost however I get the following error.

> ImportError: ../build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pyBoostHOG.so: undefined
>   symbol: _ZN2cv4cuda6Stream4NullEv.

Is there any way by which I can access the opencv cuda modules from python?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Well, I could fix it. The symbol itself describes the modules used. So we should make sure all the required modules are included.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error. And this is how I was compiling the .so file:

```
g++ `pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs` -fPIC -c flow.cpp
g++ -Wall -O3 -shared -o flow.so flow.o `pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs`
```

The error was resolved when I changed my make file to the following:

```
g++ `pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs` -fPIC -c flow.cpp
g++ -Wall -O3 -shared flow.o -o flow.so `pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs`
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

I figured out that I must include opencv2/core/cuda.hpp file (symbol _ZN2cv4cuda6Stream4NullEv reffers to: cv::cuda::Stream::Null()

But this doesn't solve the problem, because when I tried to make wrap thought swig and include these file, new error:

```
.../include/opencv2/core/cuda.hpp:317: Error: Syntax error in input(1).
```

is displayed.
Compiling another program using cv::cuda::Stream::Null() cause not error.